# How to validate a list of dictionaries using jsonschema with Python

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```py
list_of_dictionaries = [{'key1': True}, {'key2': 0.2}]
```

And I want to validate it using jsonschema package.

I created a schema like this:

```py
schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "key1": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "key2": {
                "type": "number"
            }
        },
        "required": ["enabled"]
    }
}
```

But it is not correct for my list because to make it works my list should be like this:

```py
list_dict = [{'key1': True, 'key2': 0.5}]
```

How can I create a correct schema to validate my list?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want to be using the `oneOf` construct.  Basically, you're trying to describe a list that can contain any number of two different kinds of objects.

Here's an example of use:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/defs/element"
  },
  "$defs": {
    "element": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/foo"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/bar"
        }
      ]
    },
    "foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key1": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "key1"
      ]
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "key2": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "key2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There are also `anyOf` and `allOf` combiners that might be useful to you.  Take a look at [jsonschema's documentation on combining](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html) for more information.

Comment: As a note, `oneOf` will only work if the value schemas are mutually exclusive, which might require the use of `additionalProperties: false` to achieve. This answer is good.

Comment: In the above example, "required" is doing the heavy lifting to distinguish the types, but I added "additionalProperties" to the example because I think you're right, it's better form.